What's the best free epub or pdf summarizer right now?
I don't mean just scientific or technical ebooks. I mean ebooks of other genres. Fiction, for example, like "The Great Gatsby", or "The Moonstone" by Wilkie Collins. I upload a epub of that book to that website, or app, or software, and it gives me a detailed summary of that book.
Most free services provide only what is available on official synopses or reviews without spoilers. It's very difficult to find anything worthwhile. I don't want to waste my time by reading an ebook without being told what the plot is.

I tend to just llok at Amazon, or https://www.goodreads.com/

+1 for mentioning Collins' The Moonstone.
